# Match nodes inheriting from type in XSLT

Tags: xslt, inheritance, xsd, xslt-2.0, extend

We have an XSD which defines the following:

```
<xsd:element name="Product" type="cm:Product" abstract="true" />
<xsd:complexType name="Product" abstract="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <!-- Other common elements -->
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:element name="Subscription" type="cm:Subscription" />
<xsd:complexType name="Subscription">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="cm:Product">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <!-- Subscription specific elements -->
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I need to create an XSLT which takes the product name and a few other things and convert it into a web service request. The problem is that I don't really know if the top element actually says `cm:Product`, `cm:Subscription` or something completely different (but which extends cm:Product).

Is there a way I can somehow write a template which matches both `cm:Product` elements and all elements extending `cm:Product`?

---

**Simple example input**

```
<Subscription xmlns="http://schema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <name>Basis</name>
</Subscription>
```

**What I have so far**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:cm="http://schema" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="cm">

    <xsl:param name="processID" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="RequestElement">
            <xsl:element name="processId">
                <xsl:value-of select="$processID" />
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cm:Product/cm:name">
        <xsl:element name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works if I change `cm:Product` to `cm:Subscription`, which is in my particular input xml, but the problem is that I can't know that it actually is a cm:Subscription. All I "know" is that it is an element extending `cm:Product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="element(*, cm:Product)/cm:name">
```

should do it, but you'll need to add a suitable top-level

```
<xsl:import-schema namespace="https://schema" schema-location="....." />
```

and of course it requires that your processor is schema-aware.

Comment: Seems like that would've done it if hadn't gotten this error message instead: *To use xsl:import-schema, you need the schema-aware version of Saxon* :/ Oh well...

Comment: If you're sure that your inputs will all be single elements that are of that type you may just get away with `match="*/cm:name"`

Comment: Think there might be other children down the tree with name elements too actually, otherwise that would've indeed worked.

Comment: Or anchor the match at the root: `/*/cm:name`

Comment: That's a possibility as well which would solve it for this element at least. Unfortunately there are some other cases which becomes a bit more tricky. I've seen a lot of cases of `<cm:Product xsi:type="cm:Subscription">`, `<xsl:template match="cm:Product[@xsi:type='cm:Subscription']">`, which I've found kind of ugly, but I guess this is a reason for doing it that way. Not sure it is correct according to the actual XSD though? Or is `<cm:Product xsi:type="cm:Subscription">` equivalent to `<cm:Subscription>` if `cm:Subscription` extends `cm:Product` in the XSD?

Comment: The confusing part is because your XSD uses the same names for complex types and for element declarations.  The `Product` element is declared to be of the abstract type `Product`, so you use `xsi:type` to indicate which concrete sub-type (such as `Subscription`) a particular instance of the `Product` element is using.  But then you also have a concrete `Subscription` _element_ bound to the concrete `Subscription` type.

Comment: A further complicating factor is that the template match expressions for element names use the namespace prefix mappings in force in the _stylesheet_ while the `xsi:type` values depend on the prefix mappings in the _XML document_ being processed.  I could say `<ns:Product xmlns:ns="http://schema" xsi:type="ns:Subscription">` and that would be correct with respect to the schema but wouldn't match `[@xsi:type = 'cm:Subscription']`.

Comment: Is there a way you can match `ns:Product xsi:type="ns:Subscription"` without locking the namespace prefix then?

Comment: The slightly tongue in cheek response would be "use a schema aware processor". To be honest I'd probably look at a non-XSLT solution, maybe use a schema binding tool like JAXB to map both the input and output schema to classes and code the shims by hand.

Comment: :D That's what I was worried about. Oh well, thanks for all the help! I'll def look into trying to get a schema-aware processor, but might not be posslbe. At least now I'll know :)